# Socket.IO application not starting, no output

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, ssl, socket.io

I have the following simple socket.io app :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var db = require("./libs/db.js");

var sslOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/server.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/ca.crt'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var io = require('socket.io').listen(4000,sslOptions);
```

It runs, displaying : `info: socket.io started` on launch. The page example.com:4000 outputs : `Welcome to socket.io`, all good.

Now, in another directory, I have :

```
var fs = require('fs');

var sslOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/server.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/ca.crt'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var io = require('socket.io').listen(2000,sslOptions);
```

That code (exactly the same??) doesn't output anything on launch...

socket.io versions are identical (1.1.0), both directories are chmoded the same.
What could cause such behaviour? How can I debug?

**Edit :**

When I cp the not working app in the same dir than the working app, it runs... Again, permissions are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the `node_modules/socket.io` of the working dir into the non-working one. It now works.

Still haven't got a clue what's happening. Both versions were installed using npm install, and npm socket.io version gave me the same "1.1.0".

I'll leave the question here, as it may help someone. Weird...